# How do I paginate my posts from firestore to my Javascript web app. Am not using any framework except Node.js server

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Below is the code I have tried.Am really new to programming

```
var records_per_page = 4;
  
  var first = firebase.firestore().collection("Posts").limit(records_per_page);

  first.get().then((snapshot)=>
    {
        document.getElementById("post-container").innerHTML = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function (taskValue) {
            if(snapshot.size >= 1){
                showPosts(taskValue)
                 
                    $("#next").click(function(){
                        var lastVisible = "";
                        lastVisible = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length-1];
                        showMorePosts(records_per_page,lastVisible)
                    })
             
            }
           
        });
        
    }
  );
```

But the code fetches the first and second four documents only. I have created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mwillis72/d935399f7475479dd715568e7beca8da) to show both methods showMorePosts(records_per_page,lastVisible) and showPosts(records_per_page). Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to add a lot of code.

[image: This is how my database looks like]

Comment: You can use [`offset`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#offset) to load a specific page.

Comment: I still don't get you. How am I going to use it in my query because it's not working. Am really new to programming @jabaa

Comment: You can see an example in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this, one is by using the `offset` and other is by using the functions `startsAfter()` and `limit()`.

You can use `offset` function to fetch the documents, but it is generally not a great option, because when you call this offset method in the server libraries, you still get billed for builds that you’re offsetting.

So, generally it is better to [use](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) `startsAfter()` and `limit()`, because those will only get billed for the actual work you’ve performed and none of the one you skipped.

Also you can try following this [tutorial](https://morioh.com/p/b287c3c0ee1f) on Firestore Pagination for the beginners.

Comment: I did but it returned an error.... offset is not a function

Comment: Have you tried the example from the documentation I've mentioned above?

Comment: Yes and it's the one I used to write that code in my question...

Comment: I have edited my answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: My challenge is when I click next button, it will show only the second set of documents based limit parameter but it won't show the rest when I click the button the second time. Am using document.getElememtById('post-section') +='HTML data goes hear'; in showPosts and showMorePosts methods

Comment: What is there in the showMorePosts() method? Can you provide the full code? Also please provide the Firestore database structure.

Comment: I have tried to update my question.Kindly check, it has a gist as well

Comment: It seems that you are able to fetch first and second four documents only because in the Line 7(const records_per_page = 4), you've set the variable records_per_page to 4, and then in showPosts() and showMorePosts() methods, you're giving this variable inside the limit() function. So that is why you are only able to see the first four/ second four documents only.

Comment: So what should I do to get the next four continuously as the button is clicked?

Comment: For getting next four documents, just pass a number inside limit function in your showMorePosts() method in the Line 97(.startAfter(lastVisible).limit(4)). Try this once.

Comment: I have tried but I still get the same former behavior. I have updated the gist though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create some sort of pagination so that when a person clicks next button, the next set of four posts replaces the former, continuously. However, am still figuring out on how to implement the previous button functionality so a person can load the previous sets of posts without having to refresh the page. I created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mwillis72/50a8fe25c73add8e471b25c1108f9c16). You can check it out for further progress and advise.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).